# How to extract All of reg expression matches from html page via JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, load-testing

I have a html page containing userIds of students. I need to extract all the userId values from this html page and use them in a parameter of JMeter HTTP request..

For example i have following data on htm page.

```
<input type="checkbox" StudentID="1503"
<input type="checkbox" StudentID="1504"
<input type="checkbox" StudentID="1505"
```

so on..

The value I need to send in parameter is like this
selectedIds= 1503,1504,1505 and so on..

Now I am not sure how I can get the result that i need to send in my second request. I can extract & use one value at a time but could not figure out how to get values like I require "1503,1504,1505..."

Currently my Reg Exp extractor is like this

Reference Name: myTestVar
Reg Expression: StudentID="(.+?)"
Template: $1$
MatchNo: -1

In my second request I am referencing to variable ${myTestVar}

Please guide what else I need to do to get the results in desired way..

"1504,1505,1506"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BeanShell Postprocessor:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
String finalArr = "";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<input type=\"checkbox\" StudentID=\"(\\d+?)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response);

while (matcher.find()) 
{
  finalArr = finalArr + matcher.group(1) + ",";
}
```

Or if you are using Regex Extractor then also in Beanshell Postprocessor:

```
Integer N = Integer.valueOf(vars.get("myTestVar _matchNr"));
String finalArr = "";

for(Integer i = 1; i <= N; i++)
{   
   finalArr = finalArr + (vars.get("myTestVar "+String.valueOf(i)+"_g1")) + ",";
}
```

Comment: This seems like the solution that I was looking for. I am using Regex Extractor so I think second solution will work for me. I will try it and update results here.

Comment: I have successfully solved my problem using following code in BeanShell PreProcessor..

--------
<code>
int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("student_id_RegEx_matchNr"));
String delimiter = ",";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(int i=1;i<=count;i++) { 
 sb.append(vars.get("student_id_RegEx_" + i));
 if (i == count){
 break; //to eliminate comma after the array
 }else {
  sb.append(delimiter);
 }
}
 vars.put("arrayOutPut",sb.toString()); </code>
----------

Comment: btw if you wanna to eliminate final comma you simply do this (just an option ;))
str= str.substring(0,str.length()-1);

Comment: any feedback on my answer ? if it was helpful it should be accepted and possibly upvoted so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 2):

Maybe late, but in 3.2+ you can put -1 in match number

[image]

br

Answer (score 0):

IN this case it is better to use [CSS/JQuery extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)  instead of regexp extractor:

- CSS/JQuery expression : input
- Attribute : StudentID
- Reference : myId

Then you values would be in :

- myId_1
- myId_2
  ...
- myId_N

And the number of references would be in :

- myId_matchNr

So to concatenate you can use Beanshell PostProcessor that will extract those, concat and store result in a new variables using:

> vars.put("concat", )