# Need to Extract multi value key pair using regex

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

In My Web test project one request return below json in body tag. And I wants to extract all TimeEntryIds of Each FieldItem. using single RegEx extractor (Post porcessors) because I need to pass each TimeEntryid in successive web request.

```
{
  "InvoiceItemId": 0,
  "JobId": 9999,
  "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "LastUpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "FieldItem": [
    {
      "root": false,
      "TimeEntryId": 1,
      "UpdatedDate": "2019-07-19T13:14:29.823Z"
    },
    {
      "root": false,
      "TimeEntryId": 2,
      "UpdatedDate": "2019-07-19T13:14:29.823Z"
    },
    {
      "root": false,
      "TimeEntryId": 3,
      "UpdatedDate": "2019-07-19T13:14:29.823Z"
    },
       {
      "root": false,
      "TimeEntryId": 4,
      "UpdatedDate": "2019-07-19T13:14:29.823Z"
    }
    ]
}
```

I tried "TimeEntryId":(.\d+) regex to get the value but as per GUI option we get one key\value pair only in my case it is TimeEntryId:1.

Is there any short cut to get the all Key\Value pare in single RegEx extractor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract All of reg expression matches from html page via JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894524/how-to-extract-all-of-reg-expression-matches-from-html-page-via-jmeter)

Comment: Using JSON Path Extractor will be much easy in this case

Answer (score 0):

JS solution

If you `JSON.stringify()` your data and then use `data.match(regex);` you will get back the array with all ids.

Answer (score 0):

Use below regex with Jmeter JSON Extractor post processor

```
$.FieldItem.[*].TimeEntryId
```

[image]